Flutter integration tests: run individually but not in sequence
Have a the following 2 tests.
void main() {
  setUp(() async {});

  group('integration user view tests', () {
    IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    testWidgets('No user found', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      app.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      // debugDumpLayerTree();
      var textField = find.byType(TextField);
      expect(textField, findsOneWidget);
      await tester.enterText(textField, '0');
      expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      expect(find.byKey(const Key('server_error')), findsOneWidget);
    });

    testWidgets('User found', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      app.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      var textField = find.byType(TextField);
      expect(textField, findsOneWidget);
      await tester.enterText(textField, '24');
      await tester.pump();
      expect(find.text('24'), findsOneWidget);
      // Wait for the server response
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      expect(find.byKey(const Key('user_data')), findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}

If I run each integration test individualy, it works. But if I launch both of them, the second fail.
Actually, I can see on my mobile the first test executing, but the second doesn't launch on mobile and fail immediately (TextField not found).
What am I missing?
Thank you.

It fails because the state from the first test leaks into the second.
Try to make each test starts with a clean slate
move  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); out of the group to main
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

 setUp(() async {
    // Perform any necessary setup before each test
    // Start your app or reset it to a default state if necessary
    app.main(); 
  });

you could also tearDown to ensure each test run clean.
tearDown(() async {
  // Dispose or reset the resources initialized in setUp
});

You could read more here Flutter integration test

Thank you @Yakubu. But there is a    runApp(RootApp(),); in main and I don't know how to reset.

you can re-run runApp() with a Fresh Instance sample setUp(() async {
runApp(RootApp()); // Restart your app before each test
});
